# The field "substring" on type "Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.ROOT" does not exist or is not accessible

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow

Creating a list workflow on SharePoint Designer 2013. My workflow shows no errors but after attempting to publish, comes back with "Errors were found when compiling the workflow. The workflow files were saved but cannot be run." Additional details stated, "(0, 0) Activity 'ID8090' validation failed: Property "Condition" has invalid value. Condition expression is invalid. The field "substring" on type "Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow.ROOT" does not exist or is not accessible.)"

What is or where can I find this error to fix it?

Thank you

Comment: What does the workflow look like? Have you used "substring" somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message shows, this issue is about the field "substring" in the condition expression. You can have a check it, and make sure it is valid. If it still has this issue, you can provide some screenshots about your conditions.